# Does my Hp Laptop supports SSD

Tags: ssd

I have an HP ENVY 15t-k000 CTO Notebook PC (ENERGY STAR). I want to upgrade to add **ssd** in it, but I am not sure If it has a slot available ?

Kindly help.

Below is screenshot of specs.

[image]

**Product Number:** G0T55AAR

Comment: The `dxdiag` screenshot doesn’t help all that much. Instead, try to locate the exact make and model by looking at the label that’s somewhere on the device.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks, Kindly check the updated question for product number

Comment: And any SATA HDD *can* be replaced by a SATA SSD (same form factor, same connections). Your question is about whether or not yours have also a mSATA or M.2 slot and for that you should be checking the manufacturer's specifications for your exact model.

Comment: Your edit is useless. There are DOZENS of different "HP Envy 15"s. In the bottom you should find a sticker with the exact model number. Then you can search yourself. You question isn't appropriate for this site because it shows no effort, no research.

Comment: @MichaelBay HP ENVY 15t-k000 CTO Notebook PC (ENERGY STAR)

Comment: OK, now you have everything you need (probably). Open the HP website and find out the full specifications for your exact model (HP can also identify your machine directly or by entering the serial number or part number).

Comment: Just a note: Please upgrade your BIOS, it's too old, the current version is F.55 Rev.A (Mar 9, 2018).

Comment: @Vlastimil Thanks for pointing. I will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Product Number, I found the manuals for your laptop [here.](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-envy-15-k000-notebook-pc/6936206/model/7174348/manuals?sku=G0T55AAR)

You'll need the [Maintenance and Service Guide for your laptop.](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04409752)

The surest way would be to remove the existing HDD and put in a regular 2.5" SATA SSD in its place.

The HDD/SSD options are listed on page 26, and the removal and replacement steps are listed starting from page 66.

Note that you will need to essentially disassemble the laptop to get at the HDD/SSD: the instructions for that are on pages 47-50.

You'll need appropriate tools and some knowledge in handling ESD-sensitive parts.

You might want to begin by obtaining a HP Hardware Kit 762504-001. Although it's technically not necessary (you could get the same parts off the HDD you're removing), but it is inexpensive from eBay and getting an extra kit of mounting rails and a SATA connector adapter allows you to verify the screw locations and available height without actually disassembling your laptop first.

Instead of replacing the HDD with a SATA SSD, it might be possible to install a mSATA SSD in addition to the existing HDD if your system board has a slot for it. To verify that the slot exists, I'm afraid opening the laptop will be necessary. Check item 13 on page 17. The fact that there are no procedures listed for replacing the mSATA SSD makes me worry that this option might not be really available.

Note that all of these are listed as Authorized Service Provider parts, so if your system is still under warranty, that warranty will most likely be void if you open the laptop to swap out the disk.

Comment: @sheldoncooper In a nutshell: Your laptop is NOT user serviceable. Please ask a professional. You aren't qualified for this job.